# Multiple JDK is not working properly in Ununtu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-7, ubuntu-14.04

**JDK versions (jdk1.7.0_21 and jdk1.7.0_55)**

```
root@xxx-xxx:/usr/lib/jvm# ll
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Apr  4  2013 jdk1.7.0_21/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Mar 18 09:04 jdk1.7.0_55/
```

> Installed and Configured like below.

**jdk1.7.0_21**

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javaws" 1

sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21
```

**jdk1.7.0_55**

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javac" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaws" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55
```

**and i am choosing/changing the default JDK by**

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
update-alternatives --config javaws
```

After this if i run `java -version` while `jdk1.7.0_55` is default, output's like below.

```
root@xxx-xxx:/usr/lib/jvm# java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

but while `jdk1.7.0_21` is default it gives an message like

`java: error while loading shared libraries:` **libjli.so**: `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If i issue: **locate libjli.so**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
```

So it's clear that though i selected `jdk1.7.0_21` but somehow it's still pointing to `jdk1.7.0_55`

Tried to rename the `jdk1.7.0_55` but no luck.

> Not sure how to fix this. Thanks in advance for your help :)

**Solution::** My `jdk1.7.0_21` was broken, downloaded a fresh copy form oracle untar in in `/usr/lib/jvm/` that was it.

Comment: Have you tried to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and update `java`, `javac` etc symlinks manually, with `ln`?

Comment: Comment edit timeout, so - I think you need setting `JAVA_HOME` to the "way" you switch JDK - like 0`update-alternatives --config JAVA_HOME`, or something like that.0